# Strange compiler error in simple C linked list

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to write a linked list in C. I'm using this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _node *nodep;
typedef struct _node {
    int value;
    nodep next;
} node;

int main(){
    printf("Hello World!");
    node* list = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

I get a compiler error C2275 and C2065 in line

```
    node* list = 0;
```

The code compiles when I delete `printf` or move the offending line before `printf`.

Comment: declaration should be first

Comment: Please be sure to first declaration. for c89 (MSVC)

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? If it's a dupe close it as such, but in itself I believe this is not a bad question. Certainly it is not 'off topic'. Be patient with beginners, I was not aware that mixing is not allowed either.

Comment: @mafu He could have googled the compiler error message. **That's how I solved my beginner problems.**

Comment: Well, googling did not help. For example, Microsoft says this:
Error C2065 [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ewcf0002.aspx)
Error C2275 [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76c9k4ah%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Furthermore, I could remember that similar code in college shown was compiling without any problems. :-\ Of course, they did not use VS2010 but I was not aware of the fact that VS2010 does not support C99.

EDIT: I can't make paragraphs in comments?

Comment: Those aren't terribly explanatory links, are they. The problem is that in C, you can't mix declarations and statements. That is, all your variables must be declared at the beginning of the block, before your code starts doing anything. (Note that "block scope" makes for an interesting topic on its own, and is more complex than just "declare all your variables at the start of the function".) The C99 standard introduced the ability to mix declarations and statements, but Microsoft has chosen not to support anything newer than C89 in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio doesn't support C99. Therefore you can't mix declarations and statements with this environment. Write rather:

```
/* ... */

int main(void) {
    node *list = 0; /* declaration */
    printf("Hello World!\n"); /* statement */
    return 0;
}
```

which is C89 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

make the below changes

```
node *list =NULL;
printf("\n Hello World ");
```